# iPad : Change orientation's view on load

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation

I have a problem with my app on iPad : 
In my app, I have some views in landscape and portrait and some views only in landscape. For these views I do:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

I use a UIViewController to navigate and when I am in portrait and I switch to a view who was only in landscape, I see the landscape view in portrait...
Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the base view which contains the landscaped view supports portrait, you have to restirct it.